# Как поднять эффективность сжатия GZip(в NET 3.5)

Tags: c#

Организовано сжатие файла следующим образом:

```
using (Stream fs = File.OpenRead(fileInput))
using (Stream fd = File.Create(FileOut))
using (Stream csStream = new GZipStream(fd, CompressionMode.Compress))
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int nRead;
    try
    {
        while ((nRead = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {

            csStream.Write(buffer, 0, nRead);

        }
    }
```

Хотя в msdn и написано, что GZip сам умеет распределять потоки наиболее эффективно, однако на деле получается загрузка процессоров лишь на 25%. 
Каким образом можно модифицировать этот кусок кода, чтобы задействовать как можно больше ресурсов системы, для ускорения процесса сжатия?

Comment: А почему не попробовать так: http://pastebin.com/uEdgqqEu ?

Comment: Нельзя реализовать на 3.5 Добавлю в вопрос, чтобы не было таких комментариев больше )

Comment: Ну увеличьте размер буфера хотя бы. Как вы думаете, как можно эффективно параллелизировать упаковку несчастного одного килобайта данных?

Comment: Так уж выходит, что изменяя этот параметр ничего не меняется ) при запуске VS показывает загрузку всех процессов строго на 25%, такое ощущение будто на остальные процессоры нагрузка вовсе не распределяется

Comment: Возможно, в старой версии GZip таи не умел распределять потоки как надо. Попробуйте для проверки в новой версии.